# wire:loading add class to the body tag?

Tags: laravel-livewire

when loading something slow, I show a splash screen using

```
<div wire:loading class="my-splash-screen-spinner">
   Loading.....
</div>
```

the problem is, there are still overflow scroll bars on the body or html tag.

I want to remove those. What is the way?

My question is basically: when livewire goes to loading state, how can I add a css class to the body? with that css class, I can remove the overflow from body.

Is there a way to listen to loading via livewire javascript and then do something on loading and on stop loading? (add remove class to body)

Answer (score -1):

You probably forgot to add

```
<head>
@livewireStyles
</head
```

Comment: thank you, but no. The issue is that the body still has scroll bars. My question is basically: when livewire goes to loading state, how can I add a css class to the body? with that css class, i can remove the overflow from body. Ill update the question